# Why does setState in this promise take longer to update than the same code as an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

I have 2 versions of the same fetch functions here, the first one uses promises, the second one async-await. To my understanding there should be no difference between those two, so I'd appreciate some clarification to what's actually happening here.

The following version, which uses async-await, sets the state by the time console log runs:

```
async fetchPostList(query) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${query}.json`)
  const data = await response.json()
  this.setState({ postList: data });
  console.log(this.state.postList);
}
```

Console: `Array(474) [ ... ]`

The version that uses promises sets state after the console log:

```
fetchPostList(query) {
  fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${query}.json`)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => this.setState({ postList: data }))
  console.log(this.state.postList);
}
```

Console: `Array []`

Comment: Both `console.log(this.state.postList);` results aren't related to currently fetched data, but earlier state. State will be updated later - async nature of `setState`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first function is an async function. In an async function the code pauses while the awaited promises resolve.

```
async fetchPostList(query) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${query}.json`)
  /* Pause ...*/

  const data = await response.json() 
  /* Pause ... */

  this.setState({ postList: data });
  console.log(this.state.postList);
}
```

The second function is not async, which means it runs to completion. It just fires off the promises and callbacks and continues, so the `console.log()` is called immediately after creating the promises.

```
fetchPostList(query) {
  fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${query}.json`)
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then( data => this.setState({ postList: data }))

  /* does NOT pause */
  console.log(this.state.postList);
}
```

Comment: I feel dumb now, I thought that both paused. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @MatijaxD …it's one of the more confusing parts of javascript and takes a while to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to log the updated state you must wait the Promise to resolve some data, only when you have data you can log the data itself:

```
fetchPostList(query) {
  fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/${query}.json`)
   .then( response => response.json())
   .then( data => {
     this.setState({ postList: data })
     // here you have data
     console.log(this.state.postList);
   })
// here you do not have data
}
```